# Formatting and converting column into datetime format in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime-format, col

I am fairly new to R and need help with applying operations to an entire column in a dataframe. Imagine a few values of the `date_time` column in the `df` look like this:

```
date_time
2017-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
2017-05-01T10:00:00.000Z
2017-05-01T20:00:00.000Z
...
```

Currently `date_time` is of type factor. If everything was formatted nicely, I think I want to do something similar to what I have below to convert it to DateTime (based off of what I've been seeing online):

```
df$date_time <- strptime(x = as.character(df$date_time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Does this look correct?

Assuming the code above is correct for converting the factor into DateTime, we still need to do some formatting for that to work. In order to use the code above, I have to get rid of the `T` that separates the date and time and replace that with `' '`, and cut off the `.000Z` at the end. How can I do this for the entire column?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `%s`?  Should it be `%d`?  Try `strptime(str1, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS')`  or use `library(lubridate); ymd_hms(str1)`

Comment: Yes, my apologies! Its should be `d` instead of `s`. This makes total sense, but instead of applying it to a single element, how do I apply this for the entire column?

Comment: YOu can replace `str1` with `df1$date_time`